# Replacement to Formulize / Eureqa? (it's a symbolic regression software)

Tags: linux, open-source, math, desktop-environment

Now that [Formulize / Eureqa](http://www.nutonian.com/products/pricing/) started charging $2500 a year for using it and having crippled the trial version, does anyone know of any replacements that can do similar things like find an equation given data points?

It was free, but is now out of the price range of anyone that's not a company or school.

(it's a symbolic regression software)

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.